# What type of Monstera is this plant?

Tags: identification, houseplants, aroid, monstera

I own a small *Monstera*, but I do not know which specific *Monstera*.
It is about 7 stems in a 9 cm pot.
There is only one stem that has two leaves with holes.

My guess is that it is either a ***Monstera adansonii*** **narrow form** or a ***Monstera acuminata***.

| the full plant, etc. | leaves with holes |
| --- | --- |
| [image: full plant] | [image] |
| [image] | [image] |
| [image] |  |

Comment: Good question and good illustrations; also, italicisation with bold can be conveniently done by typing one underscore immediately after the two initial asterisks and immediately before the text, & then typing one underscore immediately after the text and immediately before the two latter asterisks; We encourage you to take the [Tour], and browse through the [Help], to learn more about how the site works! Thank you! Welcome to the site!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does look like a very young plant, which makes it harder to tell exactly, especially with varieties of *M. adansonii*. It definitely looks like a *Monstera adansonii* var. *laniata* or just *Monstera laniata* for short. However, it could be just the *Monstera adansonii* var. *friedrichsthalii* AKA Narrow Form *adansonii* or *Monstera acuminata*, just because it is a young *M. adansonii*, and they all look so similar. I don’t want to say *M. laniata* is the only possibility. But I’d definitely say it’s likely the *Monstera laniata* because of the more even textured leaves that also appear to be wider in comparison to the Narrow Form *adansonii*, and the *M. acuminata* usually has more holes in the leaves.

Comment: Good detailed answer; If could include characteristics of more of the various types of _Monstera_ indicated could also be helpful; italicisation of text can be conveniently done by typing one underscore immediately before, & one underscore immediately after the text, or, by typing one asterisk immediately before, & one asterisk immediately after the text; We encourage you to take the [Tour], and browse through the [Help], to learn more about how the site works! Thank you! Welcome to the site!